# Disable UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm stumped at why this code isn't working. I have a login button that I want to disable when the user isn't logged in.

I have a UIButton delared in my .h file like so:

```
   IBOutlet UIButton *myBtn;
```

I've set up a referencing outlet in Interface Builder to this button.

In my .m file, I've tried:

```
[myBtn setEnabled: NO];
```

and

```
myBtn.enabled = NO;
```

But neither of these disable the button in the conditional statement I'm in. (I want to disable the login button when the user successfully logs in)

I'm able to do this with two other buttons on the same screen, so I know the code is correct. I don't throw any errors, so I think the object exists. The references to myBtn change color in XCode, too, so it appears to be a valid reference.

I must be missing something. What am I doing wrong here? (I'm a Windows developer, relatively new at Objective-C)

Comment: in your .h file, it should be IBOutlet UIButton *myBtn. needs a pointer. But I assume you might be just shortening it for the question purposes. Where have you declared it? as a property? if so, it needs to be synthesised.

Comment: Ah, forgot the asterisk (I'm typing on another computer)...

Comment: Add `NSAssert(myBtn, @"Button is nil!");` in the line before you try to disable the button. If you see an exception `myBtn` is nil and you did not connect it to an actual UIButton instance.

Answer (score 9):

It seems ok to me. Are you *synthesizing* the button? Try

```
self.myBtn.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for Swift3 solution

```
var myBtn = UIButton()
myBtn.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be setting up your button as a IBOutlet.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myBtn;
```

That way you can connect that button in storyboards.  Which could be your issue.

Then call this to disable.

```
[_myBtn setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do try this ..

In `.h` :

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *myBtn;
```

In `.m` :

```
@synthesize myBtn;
```

And then,replace your `[myBtn setEnabled: NO];` code with `[self.myBtn setEnabled: NO];` code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for swift code:

```
var button = UIButton()
button.enabled = false //disable the button
```